# javascript DOM help required

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

```
FRAME F=2
id="slideBlock"
```

TAG is DIV

I tried but its not finding the element.

```
var frames = window.frames;
var x = frames[1].document.getElementById("slideBlock");
```

Comment: I think you have to use `.contentDocument`

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as the parent window? If not, you can't access its DOM.

Answer (score 0):

An id is for a single unique element.

try ...

```
  const frame = document.getElementById('slideBlock');
```

if its an array of tags try..

```
  const frame = document.getElementsByTagName('your-tag-here')[your-index-here];
```

Comment: What's your actual code? is it a iframe in a div? is slideBlock the id of the div or the iframe?